# Delphi: How to allow setting a TClass-property of a TCollectionItem at design time

Tags: class, delphi, set, design-time, tcollectionitem

I'm developing a component that works on several classes.
In order to allow adding the list of managed classes, I've written a TCollection's inherited class in which each item (inherited from TCollectionItem) defines a published "TargetClassName" property.
The "TargetClassName" property's setter function, calls the following function in order to find the corrisponding TClass:

```
function FindAnyClass(const Name: string): TClass;
var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  typ: TRttiType;
  list: TArray<TRttiType>;
begin
  Result := nil;
  ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
  list := ctx.GetTypes;
  for typ in list do
    begin
      if typ.IsInstance and (EndsText(Name, typ.Name)) then
        begin
          Result := typ.AsInstance.MetaClassType;
          break;
        end;
    end;
  ctx.Free;
end;
```

(Thanks to Dalija Prasnikar for writing the function [Get class by its name in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29471798/get-class-by-its-name-in-delphi)).

Now, I'm wondering if there's a better way to allow adding classes to a TCollectionItem at design time.. What do you think about it?
Hope to read interesting solutions!
Thanks to all.

Comment: RTTI is almost surely the wrong solution.

Comment: That's why I'm looking for a better solution. For the moment, I didn't found any other way to add classes at design time.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest a solution without a better idea of what the problem is. As it stands you've presented your solution but not really described the problem.

Comment: This is the type of situation where a small list of registered classes is probably a better choice. Have each desired class register itself at startup, and then you can loop through that list when needed. That will work at runtime, anyway. For design-time, you will likely have to write a custom property editor that enumerates the project's units looking for classes that have a common ancestor, or implement a common interface, or are marked with a common attribute, etc.

Comment: @David Heffernan: The problem is that I don't really know any appreciable way to set a TClass property at design time. The one exposed, is just a "fallback solution" that uses the classname to get the TClass. I would like to find out a clean solution. Please, tell me which part is unclear and I'll try to explain it better.

Comment: Which classes would you like to set at designtime? And with what purpose? Are those the classes of components? Other classes too? Can you give an example?

Comment: Classes that could be added should be all inherited from TComponent. My component has a function named "LoadComponents(Target : TComponent)" that adds components that match with one of the managed classes (if Target.Components[i] is Self.FClasses[j] then ...).
The goal is that to fill a variable number of arrays with components. In this way, as an example, I can easily apply changes to all components whose class is inherited by one of the managed classes (...Or any other thing I need to do with them).

Comment: I still can't work out what you are trying to do. Never mind.

Comment: That's just `TList<T>` surely

Comment: No. But I don't see why you need to write your entire program using the form designer.

Comment: I haven't answered. I commented. I still don't see why you need to do this at design time. A lot of people fall into the trap of trying to do everything at design time rather than writing code. Perhaps that's happening here.

Comment: I guess you know more about all this than I do. You don't need my help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

in creation on TCollection You need To introduce Collation Class
it's Posible in two way 
1 : hard coded in create time X := TMycollation.Create(TMyCollationClass)
2 : your solution X := TMycollation.Create(FindAnyClass('TMyCollationClass'));

Comment: My goal is that to set a TComponentClass proprerty at design time.
Something like this:

TMyCollectionItem = class(TCollectionItem)
....
published
  MyProperty : TComponentClass ...; // <-- I would like to set this at design time
end;